# Interleaving Two Threads in Java not do in order

Tags: java, multithreading

I wanted to check if between two or more threads that access a shared resource without mutual exclusion would have presented interleaving problems and I noticed that if I increase the number within the condition, then from 50 I put 1000, I notice that the threads no longer run first one and then the other, but overlap, why? And how can I solve this problem?
This is the code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Mutex {

  private int val;
  public Mutex(int val) {

    this.val=val;
  }

  public int getVal() {
    return val;
  }

  public void printVal() {
    int i=0;
    while (true) {

     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+this.getVal());
      if(i==50)
        break;
      else
        i++;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final Mutex m1=new Mutex(1);
    final Mutex m2 = new Mutex(2);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        m1.printVal();
      }
    },"THREAD-1").start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        m2.printVal();
      }
    },"THREAD-2").start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting the threads to run in sequential order in the first place?

Comment: Because when I start with i==50 it prints correctly, if I put an high number It will print THREAD-1 SO THREAD-2 SO THREAD-1 and It is not correct

Comment: No, you don't understand my question. Why do you think that is not correct? You do know how multithreading works?

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand why with low numbers it executes it correctly and with high no

Comment: I probably misunderstood how interleaving should work ?

Comment: `Thread t1 = new Thread(...` and `Thread t2 = new Thread(...` followed by `t1.start(); t1.join(); t2.start();`. Also you don't need to `import java.lang.*;`

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What is happening instead? Where do you see a `shared ressource` here? It's entirely unclear what you think is wrong here.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution without using the join

Comment: I thought that the parameter "i" was the shared one, but if it is as you say I was wrong, would you have an example of interleaving with the same shared resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start THREAD-1,  then you start THREAD-2.  When the task is short (EG stopping at 50) THREAD-1 runs to completion before you get to starting THREAD-2.  When the task is longer, then the two threads may overlap

Answer (score 0):

Some changes in yout code. Please move to main method

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Mutex {

  private int val;
  public Mutex(int val) {

    this.val=val;
  }

  public int getVal() {
    return val;
  }

  public void printVal() {
    int i=0;
    while (true) {

     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+this.getVal());
      if(i==50)
        break;
      else
        i++;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final Mutex m1=new Mutex(1);
    final Mutex m2 = new Mutex(2);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        m1.printVal();
      }
    },"THREAD-1");
    t1.start();
    t1.join(); //it will lead thread 1 to finish first
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        m2.printVal();
      }
    },"THREAD-2").start();
  }
}
```